How to define callback signature based on first arg?
I need to define a function that receives a data (array or object) and a callback, and I am unable to fix the types of the callback arguments based on the data args.
Here is a short example:
declare const each: <
    V,
    T extends Array<V> | Record<K, V>,
    K extends PropertyKey = T extends Array<any> ? number : PropertyKey,
>(
    data: T,
    callback: (d: T extends Array<any> ? T[number] : V, k: K) => void,
) => void;

function bar(arr: Array<Set<number>>, obj: Record<string, Date>) {
    each(arr, (v, k) => {
        // OK v is Set<number>, k is number 
    });

    each(obj, (v, k) => {
        // KO v is unknown instead of "Date", k is string it's OK
    });
}

Playground

There is no inference site for V. You've already written T[number] instead of V for the Array, why not T[keyof T] for the Record, as shown in this playground link and then dispense with V entirely? Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

Don't declare three more-or-less independent type parameters V, T and K. Use only T, and infer the rest using conditional types:
declare const each: <
    T extends Array<unknown> | Record<string, unknown>
>(
    data: T,
    callback: T extends Array<infer V>
        ? (d: V, i: number) => void
        : (d: T[keyof T], k: keyof T) => void
) => void;

(updated playground)
